# How to disable "swipe" for taphold

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, touch

I have found that the taphold (long click) function for jQuery Mobile also seems to cause elements to change the same way by "swiping" as well.

A quick proof of this undesired effect is:

http://api.jquerymobile.com/taphold/

If I "swipe" the box well before 750ms it changes color and it bypasses me having to do a taphold (long click).

As well as this:

http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_events_taphold

If I "swipe" the text it also dissapears the same way taphold does.

Threshold changes I tried did not fix this and I would like to know if anyone has a solution to prevent a taphold event on an element from being triggered by "swiping" it as well?

Note:
I put "swipe" in quotes because I think it is inherently caused by taphold and not a seperate swipe event. I can't be certain but I have tried tried several things out such as combining swipe and taphold events on a single element with varying thresholds which lead me to think this.

Comment: true, `taphold` has no vertical/horizontal distance threshold. https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/blob/master/js/events/touch.js#L83-L140

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested in an alternative solution. I've discovered a plugin by Rich Adams that has the fix already in place. https://github.com/richadams/jquery-taphold/blob/master/taphold.js

It implements specified boundries for the taphold event. Guess still need to wait for the jquery mobile official to set some boundries to the taphold event of their own but this plugin works just as well and solves the issue for disabling "swipe" on taphold.